# One To Many Bidirectional relationship implementation postgres SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, microservices, spring-boot-jpa

I am seeking the suggestion for implementation of Many-to-One mapping classes and was hoping if anyone could provide me a clear picture.

One to One mapping Scenario: Table foo and Table childfoo Foo has one to many and many to one relationship

Here is the JPA entity implementation I've made so far:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "foo")
public class foo implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "foo_id")
private Integer fooId;


@Column(name="someId")
private Integer someId

@Column(name="comevalue")
private String somevalue;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="foo", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<ChildFoo> userRecords = new HashSet<>();
}
```

ChildFoo class

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude ="foo")
@Table(name = "childfoo")
public class Childfoo implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8142203085486540150L;
    
    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_record_id")
    private Integer childfooId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
     @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private Foo foo;
    
    @Column(name="child_name")
     private String childName;

   }
```

I've created a repository for the Foo and child foo to be used in the controller to save the data.

Controller code to add the foo and childfoo:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.set...

   ChildFoo childFoo = new ChildFoo();
        childFoo.setChildName("abc");
        childFoo.setFoo(foo);

  childFoo.save(childFoo);
```

EDIT:

Now I'll need to get the childFoo using the someId and someName value . I tried using the join but was wondering if there is any effective way to write a query in ChildFooRepository/ Foo Repository to pass someId and someName.

I have this query in the childFoo and getting the error:

```
SELECT cf from schema.child_foo cf join schema.foo f"+""
            + " ON cf.foo_id = f.foo_id"+""
                    + " where f.some_id = :someid AND 
               f.somename= :somename
```

Shall I be adding this query in the Foo repository and not the child foo repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that both `Foo` and `ChildFoo` are persisted, and that the bidirectional association is synchronized (so when calling `setFoo(foo)` on the child you should also add `childFoo` to the corresponding collection of children on the parent).

So in your case you will probably also need to call `save` on the parent.

(see documentation samples on [cascading operations](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) and [synchronizing bidirectional associations](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/))

Comment: What would be the jpa repository method I could use to get the childfoo using extraId and extraname(in foo) as input. Do I need to write a custom join query? I wrote the join query, but am getting error child_foo_id wasn't found on the resultset...I tried to use the query from above but am getting error saying missing from..I must be missing something here!!

Comment: please don't mix different questions into one, create a new one instead.

but in this case, I'd probably read through the jpa repository documentation and/or existing stackoverflow posts first (e.g. you might have a look at this recently answered question also addressing a problem of querying  by an attribute of related entities : https://stackoverflow.com/a/67494555/13156126